# curl FTP access denied

Tags: curl, libcurl

I am using curl php API to access FTP links. On a particular site, it gives error code 9 (access denied). However the link is accessible from IE and Firefox.

Then I run curl command line and it gave the same "access deinied" results.

```
> d:>\curl -v ftp://ftp1.example.com/outgoing/EHF/dbex10win_en.zip
> * About to connect() to ftp1.example.com port 21 (#0)
> *   Trying 204.50.113.145...
> * connected
> * Connected to ftp1.example.com (204.50.113.145) port 21 (#0) < 220 Microsoft FTP Service
> > USER anonymous < 331 Anonymous access allowed, send identity (e-mail name) as password.
> > PASS ftp@example.com < 230-Welcome to Example FTP site! < 230 Anonymous user logged in.
> > PWD < 257 "/" is current directory.
> * Entry path is '/'
> > CWD outgoing < 550 outgoing: Access is denied.
> * Server denied you to change to the given directory
> * Connection #0 to host ftp1.example.com left intact curl: (9) Server denied you to change to the given directory
> > QUIT < 221
> * Closing connection #0
```

But the link works fine in Firefox. What is wrong with cUrl here? Thanks

Comment: If you specify a full path to a directory, does that make a difference?

Comment: Where do you use libcurl?!?

Answer (score 9):

Try fiddling with curl's option --ftp-method

> ```
>    --ftp-method [method]
>           (FTP) Control what method curl should use to reach a file on  a
>           FTP(S) server. The method argument should be one of the follow‐
>           ing alternatives:
>
>           multicwd
>                  curl does a single CWD operation for each path  part  in
>                  the given URL. For deep hierarchies this means very many
>                  commands. This is how RFC 1738 says it should  be  done.
>                  This is the default but the slowest behavior.
>
>           nocwd  curl  does  no CWD at all. curl will do SIZE, RETR, STOR
>                  etc and give a full path to the  server  for  all  these
>                  commands. This is the fastest behavior.
>
>           singlecwd
>                  curl  does  one  CWD  with the full target directory and
>                  then operates on the file "normally" (like in the multi‐
>                  cwd  case).  This  is  somewhat more standards compliant
>                  than 'nocwd' but without the full penalty of 'multicwd'.
> ```

Answer (score 1):

That means the specified directory does not exist in the remote/ftp server, hence the message "Server denied you to change to the given directory".

That message has got nothing to do with the local machine you are trying to download files into.

Login to `ftp datacenter.myserver.com` and see if the source directory exists.

Answer (score 0):

it has nothing to do with `CURL`  the error was very explicit `Server denied you to change to the given directory` ... Its simply an access issue ...

Adding `username` and `password` simply resolves the issue ...

Why it works on browser ... There is no automatic directory redirection .. why is it not working on curl ??? curl would use standard  `ftp` process which would involve login before you change to relevant directory

You can what to use it directly via php .... `fopen` or `file_get_content` is a cheat i use ... works as if your are accessing it via browser

Example

```
 set_time_limit(0);
 file_put_contents("out.zip", file_get_contents('ftp://204.50.113.145/outgoing/EHF/dbex10win_en.zip'));
```

works like charm